# Can we trigger multiple dmn from java code

Tags: java, drools, rules, jbpm, dmn

I have a project in business central with 8 dmn models. Is there any way to trigger all the 8 models from java code in a single api call, like we triggering many drl files in single api call?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

DRL files belong to a defined Knowledge base/KieBase, and you create a KieSession from a given KieBase. That is the reason why when inserting Facts/Events into a KieSession and firing, several rules from the several DRLs are evaluated, as they belong to a specified Knowledge base.

DMN models instead are not identified by a Knowledge base, but are identified by their `{ namespace, name }` coordinates.

There is no single command to execute a series of DMN models ootb, especially since the required InputData(s) might vary between each model.
eg: a given DMN model requires InputData `Name` and `Age`, while another DMN model requires InputData `Customer` and `Product`.

You can however orchestrate a series of `KieCommand`(s) in a batch which would evaluate each DMN model iteratively based on your requirement, or chain the calls from the Kie Server Client (Java API) analogously.

Answer (score 0):

Usually when i test/verify the output from dmn model using this:

```
    HashMap<String, Object> input = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    input.put("variable1", value1);
    input.put("variable2", value2);
    List<DMNDecisionResult> decision = jbpmDmnService.getDmnDecision(input, containerId,
            dmnNamespace, dmnModel);
    for (DMNDecisionResult dr : decision) {
        log.info("Decision: {}, Result: {}", dr.getDecisionName(), dr.getResult());
        }
```

If triggering multiple dmn then will be calling this method
jbpmDmnService.getDmnDecision(input, containerId,
dmnNamespace, dmnModel);
multiple times based on the dmn's necessary inputs, container, namespace and model

DMNDecisionResult from package org.kie.dmn.api.core

the getDmnDecision method content:

```
    KieServicesConfiguration conf = KieServicesFactory.newRestConfiguration(jbpmUrl, initUsername, initPassword);
    KieServicesClient kieServicesClient = KieServicesFactory.newKieServicesClient(conf);
    log.info("URL [{}], Namespace[{}], Model[{}]",jbpmUrl,namespace,model);
    DMNServicesClient dmnClient = kieServicesClient.getServicesClient(DMNServicesClient.class);
    DMNContext dmnContext = dmnClient.newContext();

    for (Map.Entry<String, Object> con: context.entrySet()) {
        dmnContext.set(con.getKey(), con.getValue());
    }
    ServiceResponse<DMNResult> serverResp = dmnClient.evaluateAll(containerId, namespace, model, dmnContext);
    DMNResult dmnResult = serverResp.getResult();
```